# stack around the variable 'tabRatio' was corrupted

Tags: c

I use this code to see the course of the function sin:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<time.h> 
#define PI 3.14159265

void ratio(double *tabRatio)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        do {
            printf("Enter %d wspolczynnik:", i + 1);
            scanf("%lf", tabratio + i);
        } while (!*(tabratio + i));
        printf("%f", *(tabratio + i));
    }
}
void scope(int* fieldmin, int* fieldmax, int* frequency, int *size)
{
    do {
        printf("Podaj dolny zakres dziedziny :");
        scanf("%d", fieldmin);
        printf("Podaj gorny zakres dziedziny :");
        scanf("%d", fieldmax);
    } while (*fieldmin >= *fieldmax);
    do {
        printf("Podaj czestotliwosc probkowania :");
        scanf("%d", frequency);
    } while (*frequency > *fieldmax - *fieldmax);
    // printf("%f",*dolnyzakres);
    *size = *fieldmax - *fieldmin;
}
void function(double*tabRatio, int* fieldmin, int* fieldmax, double*result, int* size)
{
    double x;
    int j;
    x = *fieldmin;
    //int rozmiar = 10;
    printf("The course of the function:");
    printf(" %d", *size);
    for (j = 0; j < *size; j++)
    {
        result[j] = tabRatio[0] * sin(((tabRatio[1] + tabRatio[2])*PI / 180)*x + tabRatio[3]);
        printf("\ny(%lf)=%lf", x, result[j]);
        x += ((*fieldmax - *fieldmax) / *size);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int *fieldmin, *fieldmax, *frequency, *size;
    double tabRatio[4];
    double *result;
    ratio(&tabRatio);
    scope(&fieldmin, &fieldmax, &frequency, &size);
    function(&tabRatio, &fieldmin, &fieldmax, &result, &size);
}
```

Visual Studio gives me the following error:

Stack around the variable 'tabRatio' was corrupted.
Stack around the variable 'result' was corrupted.

Please help!

Comment: Your code does not compile please correct it and add the needed lines.

Comment: I've incorporated the code from your comments so that what is in the question can be compiled. Code that can be compiled is much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is how you pass your variables. You declare your functions to expect pointers to variables which is not a wrong thing to do but in this case completely unnecessary. Then you declare pointers in your main and pass their addresses to the functions where your compiler should warn you about incompatible pointer types. If it does not warn you enable warnings of your compiler they are important especially for beginners!

Back to your problem. Not only do you unnecessarily use pointers, if you would pass them correctly you would pass uninitialized pointers. If you declare a pointer you need to initialize it with the address of allocated memory.

```
int * num = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* Do not forget to free it */
```

otherwise it points to somewhere in your memory and accessing it is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) which can lead to every possible outcome. In your case however you are not needed to use most of the pointers. Use pointers only if you want to modify a value inside a function and expect it to be available outside of the functions scope. Otherwise you can pass it by value. So the only variable which would be needed to be passed by reference is propably `result` and `tabRatio`. And even these would not be needed to be declared as a pointer (tapRatio is an array which decayes to a pointer but still). So you can simply declare `result` as an int and then pass its address

```
int result;
function(&result);
```

I did not look for other bugs in your code but this is what triggers you error message.

EDIT: 
If nothing of the above makes sense to you consider to get a good `C` book before continuing

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the message still appears, if I should change in int main double result* to double result